# Typescript Mongoose: Why are methods of aggregated documents undefined

Tags: typescript, mongoose, methods, model, aggregate

When using mongoose aggregate it returns an array of ProfileDocuments.
The Documents in the result array do not contain the methods of the ProfileDocument implementation.
Which leads to being unable to call document methods like checkPassword on the documents from the database.

Aggregate Example

```
ProfileSchema.statics.findByLogin = async function (login: string) {
  // why do methods of aggregated documents not work?
  const results = await this.aggregate([{
    $match: { 
      $or:[{username: login}, {mail: login}]
    }
  }])

  if (results.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('Profile not found')
  }

  const profile = await this.findById(results[0]._id)

  console.log(results[0].checkPassword)
  console.log(profile.checkPassword)

  return profile
}
```

Console Output

```
undefined
[Function (anonymous)]
```

Method implementation

```
interface ProfileDocument extends IProfile, Document {
  getDisplayname: () => Promise<string>
}

ProfileSchema.methods.checkPassword = async function (password: string) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.pass)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thakur mentioned aggregate returns raw documents. Mongoose offers a hydrate method to add the methods to a document.

Use `ProfileSchema.hydrate(doc)` or in the context of the static method `this.hydrate(doc)` returns ProfileDocuments.

```
/**
 * Shortcut for creating a new Document from existing raw data, pre-saved in the DB.
 * The document returned has no paths marked as modified initially.
 */
hydrate(obj: any): EnforceDocument<T, TMethods>;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As per [`mongoose`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) docs,

> The documents returned from **aggregates** are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! And what would be an appropriate way to cast them into Models without doing a second request?

Comment: @Grifting I have less experience with MongoDb. Can you try `const resultDocuments = results.map(result=>new ProfileSchema(result));` which I guess should give the Document shape back ?

Comment: Takur sadly it didn't work. I also tried making a Hydrated document as described in the API but it didnt work.

Comment: @Thakur I found a solution the ProfileSchema has a method called hydrate so ProfileSchema.hydrate(doc) or in the context of the static method this.hydrate(doc) works.